# Failed to open TCP connection to plugins:8140

Tags: puppet

I am deploying several vm's in ganeti with open source puppet, when I run puppet agent in this specific host I keep get this error:

```
Info: Retrieving pluginfacts
Info: Retrieving plugin
Error: /File[/var/lib/puppet/lib]: Failed to generate additional resources using 'eval_generate': Failed to open TCP connection to plugins:8140 (getaddrinfo: Name or service not known)
Error: /File[/var/lib/puppet/lib]: Could not evaluate: Could not retrieve file metadata for puppet://plugins: Failed to open TCP connection to plugins:8140 (getaddrinfo: Name or service not known)
Info: Caching catalog for host.domain.net
Info: Applying configuration version '1476293845'
Notice: /Stage[main]/Apt::Update/Exec[apt_update]/returns: executed successfully
Notice: Finished catalog run in 6.57 seconds
```

I have included several modules to this host, and the funny thing is that they are deployed except one module (facts_module), therefore my `/etc/facter/facts.d/` is empty as well as `/var/lib/puppet/facts.d/`.

Remarkable is that this host can not resolve "puppet", rather the puppetmaster. I am using srv record for the zone and I can resolve it from the host.

Can some one help with this? Do you need further information?
Thanks in advanced!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could fix the issue! I had a typo in my ganeti-os-image in my `/etc/puppet/puppet.conf`, which looks like this:

```
........
pluginsource = puppet://plugins <-- with only two forward slashes
pluginfactsource = puppet:///pluginfacts
........
```

instead of:

```
........
pluginsource = puppet:///plugins <-- three forward slashes
pluginfactsource = puppet:///pluginfacts
........
```

This is a new image, therefore only this specific host was affected. Thanks